# Typescript Error TS2345: Argument of type '(o: Class) => Class' is not assignable to parameter of type '(o: SuperClass) => SuperClass'

Tags: typescript, subclass

I have:

```
class Cache {
    constructor(f: (o: CachableDBObject) => CachableDBObject) {
    }
}

abstract class CachableDBObject {
}

class Car extends CachableDBObject {
    static create = new Cache((o: Car) => {
        return o;
    })
    s: string;
}
```

The tsc-compiler (and eslint) tell me:

Argument of type '(o: Car) => Car' is not assignable to parameter of type '(o: CachableDBObject) => CachableDBObject'.
Types of parameters 'o' and 'o' are incompatible.
Property 's' is missing in type 'CachableDBObject' but required in type 'Car'.ts(2345)

Why? Should'nt the constructor of Cache accept a function with a subclass of "CachableObject" as a parameter?

Comment: Functions are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in their parameter types.  Does [this demonstration](https://tsplay.dev/W4b0KN) explain why your code isn't type safe?

Comment: Yeah, right. Removed the "syntax-error". But still - after reading the link content - don't understand why I shouldn't be able to use a "Car" as a parameter because it IS a CachableObject. 
Cite: "Many programming language type systems support subtyping. For instance, if the type Cat is a subtype of Animal, then an expression of type Cat should be substitutable wherever an expression of type Animal is used." Isn't that exactly what I am doing?

Comment: Did you see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W4b0KN)?  If your code were correct, there'd be no compiler error, yet there's a huge runtime error.  You have to be more *accepting* in your parameters, not more *restrictive*, in order to be type safe.  Imagine a veterinarian that advertises "we provide medical care to animals" but then turns you away because your pet isn't a cat, because "a cat IS an animal". Presumably you'd agree that's false advertising, right?

Comment: I realize what I have been blind to. Thanks! And yes, I actually didn't see your extension to the example - it was too light at night here. Thanks!!